# What does the following code from session.php from CakePHP do?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to understand a method in the CakePHP source code. Following is the code taken from [session.php](https://github.com/Dieterbe/cake/blob/master/libs/session.php).

```
    function __startSession() {
        if (headers_sent()) {
            if (empty($_SESSION)) {
                $_SESSION = array();
            }
            return false;
        } elseif (!isset($_SESSION)) {
            session_cache_limiter ("must-revalidate");
            session_start();
            header ('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
            return true;
        } else {
            session_start();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Why not just `session_start`? Why the checks for `headers_sent` and what is the meaning of `header ('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');`? IN what situations will `empty($_SESSION)` or `!isset($_SESSION)` evaluate to true? An explanation of all the code is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

quick googling on the header provides some nice info.
It is for IE6, to fix its problem with third party cookies (in cases where you db data come from a different domain/IP than your webserver).
You can read more [here](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/p3p_in_ie6_frustrating_failure.html)

Answer (score 2):

`session_start()` usually send a cookie into the http response in order to always use the same session for a user.

If the `headers_sent()` is true, then it is too late to send this cookie (cookies are in headers of the response). So this check is to avoid a PHP error.

P3P headers are for privacy policies but are actually only implemented in Internet Explorer.

Comment: what is the purpose the code inside the `if (headers_sent()) {` block?

Comment: The code make sure you have a $_SESSION object. Because after having called session_start() you usually want to read and write from $_SESSION.